# Slow / Non-working remote Docker via context

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm using Docker context on Windows to access remote Docker instances on local and remote networks (connected via ssh). This worked for me without any problems until few days back. Until then I have a lot of issues with that.

Every command including simple `docker ps` takes a lot of time (30sec+) and often doesn't complete at all.

(When trying the same commands from Linux/WSL, everything is working fine).

When I'm trying any command with `--debug` param, I see following:

```
docker-compose --debug -f docker-compose.yml build app
time="2023-09-03T20:51:42+02:00" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-o ConnectTimeout=30 -l dev -- 192.168.0.222 docker system dial-stdio]"
time="2023-09-03T20:51:44+02:00" level=debug msg="using default config store \"C:\\\\Users\\\\lv\\\\.docker\\\\buildx\""
time="2023-09-03T20:51:44+02:00" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-o ConnectTimeout=30 -l dev -- 192.168.0.222 docker system dial-stdio]"
time="2023-09-03T20:52:14+02:00" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-o ConnectTimeout=30 -l dev -- 192.168.0.222 docker system dial-stdio]"
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                     docker:esxi
time="2023-09-03T20:52:44+02:00" level=debug msg="using default config store \"C:\\\\Users\\\\lv\\\\.docker\\\\buildx\""
time="2023-09-03T20:52:44+02:00" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-o ConnectTimeout=30 -l dev -- 192.168.0.222 docker system dial-stdio]"
time="2023-09-03T20:53:15+02:00" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-o ConnectTimeout=30 -l dev -- 192.168.0.222 docker system dial-stdio]"
time="2023-09-03T20:53:45+02:00" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-o ConnectTimeout=30 -l dev -- 192.168.0.222 docker system dial-stdio]"
time="2023-09-03T20:53:46+02:00" level=debug msg="commandconn: starting ssh with [-o ConnectTimeout=30 -l dev -- 192.168.0.222 docker system dial-stdio]"
listing workers for Build: failed to list workers: Unavailable: connection error: desc = "transport: failed to write client preface: write |1: file already closed"
```

I tried it on several windows computers and also on several remote servers including new ones but still with the same result.

I think this is probably caused by some latest windows-side update but I cat't find any other simillary isue.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Edit: Added information that this is probably windows-only issue. When testing the same from Linux or WSL (on the same computer), everything is working fast as expected.

Comment: Have you tried SAR on any of these servers?

Comment: Can you pleasee be more specific? What do you mean by SAR?

Comment: Setting the environment variable DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 seems to help a little. With this flag, I am able to use Docker at all, albeit very slowly.

Comment: https://github.com/sargraph/sargraph.github.io

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's a server side issue. I already tried 4 different servers including new empty Ubuntu installation with still the same result ;-(

I also tried two different client computers with also same results.

Comment: Just figured out that this is probably windows-client issue, when testing the same thing from the WSL on the same computer, docker is fast as expected

Comment: Why you're guys voting for quection close without any comment?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered same issue with newer versions of Docker Desktop recently, while using older versions (e.g. 4.12) of Docker Desktop solved my problem.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Docker Desktop 4.24.2 on Windows 10 22H2.
But not when using WSL2/Ubuntu 22.04 with the same Docker Desktop for Windows version (Docker->Settings->Resources->WSL Integration).

- ssh -V on Ubuntu 22.04 told me that it uses ssh 8.9
- ssh -V on Windows 10 told me that it uses ssh 8.1

Updating ssh on Windows, following this description https://ardislu.dev/upgrade-openssh-windows (originated from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-update-to-openssh-85/a570aca3-4d07-46c9-acfe-e0ae3ab912ae) solved the problem.

Binaries: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v8.9.1.0p1-Beta